# Java - super reference

Tags: java, super

So I want to add a toString() Method for a subclass of another class. How do I add super in it to incorporate the things already done by the superclass? 
In my code you can see that I have  a class Person with several private variables, name, gender, and age. How do I use the toString method that was used in class Person into the toString method for the class Teacher? Thanks

Here's my code:

```
class Person {

protected String myName; // name of the person
protected int myAge; // person's age
protected String myGender; // "M" for male, "F" for female
// constructor

public Person(String name, int age, String gender) {
    myName = name;
    myAge = age;
    myGender = gender;
}

public String getName() {
    return myName;
}

public int getAge() {
    return myAge;
}

public String getGender() {
    return myGender;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    myName = name;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    myAge = age;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    myGender = gender;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return myName + ", age: " + myAge + ", gender: " + myGender;

}
}


class Teacher extends Person {

protected String mySubject; // Student Id Number
protected double mySalary; // grade point average
// constructor

public Teacher(String name, int age, String gender,
        String subject, double salary) {
// use the super class' constructor
    super(name, age, gender);
// initialize what's new to Student
    mySubject = subject;
    mySalary = salary;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return mySubject;
}
public double getSalary() {
    return mySalary;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    mySubject = subject;

}
public void setSalary(double salary) {
    mySalary = salary;
}
@Override
public String toString() {

}
```

Comment: Try figuring out what `super.toString()` is as a variable and what you can do with those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a call to super.toString() in teacher

```
public String toString()
{
   return super.toString()
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem then you can mark this as the "Accepted Answer"